# ConfigurationException: Could not locate cfg.xml resource [/hibernate.cfg.xml]

Tags: java, hibernate, java-ee, configuration

Выводит исключение ConfigurationException: Could not locate cfg.xml resource [/hibernate.cfg.xml]

Код создания сессии

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
            configuration.configure("/main/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml");
            StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().
                    applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
            sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());
```

[image: Структура проекта]

Что я делаю не так?
Пробовал прописывать так

```
configuration.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
```

и так

```
configuration.configure("src/main/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml");
```

а также

```
File file = new File("src/main/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml");
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
            configuration.configure(file);
```

Но не помогает...

Comment: может так сработает : configuration.configure(new File(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("hibernate.cfg.xml").toURI()))

Comment: Помогло!!! Спасибо - а в чем был прикол?

Comment: я почти не трогал чистый hibernate без спринга, поэтому не могу сказать

Comment: Файл надо класть в стандартную папку с ресурсами.